# How to display html elements defined in xml file on JSP page

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I'm currently working on a web application where in I'm continuously adding new columns to the database tables for new projects. I don't want to keep any dependency on Java program to display new column details on JSP page hence I want to define each and every html element/components including attributes in the XML file and want to load them dynamically on the web page (JSP). I know we can read below XML file using any Java XML parser but actual problem is while placing the html elements on the JSP page.

I'm using struts 2 framework.

Sample XML file

```
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ROOTCOMPONENT [
<!ATTLIST COMPONENT
    COMP_NAME CDATA #REQUIRED
    COMP_TYPE CDATA #REQUIRED
    LABLE CDATA #IMPLIED
    SIZE CDATA #IMPLIED
    TABLE_NAME CDATA #IMPLIED  
    COLUMN_NAME CDATA #IMPLIED  
>
]>
<ROOTCOMPONENT >
<COMPONENT COMP_NAME="INPUT" COMP_TYPE="TEXT"  LABLE="User Name" /> 
<COMPONENT COMP_NAME="INPUT" COMP_TYPE="PASSWORD"  LABLE="Password"/> 
</ROOTCOMPONENT>
```

Would it be possible? Does anyone knows how it can be achieved? Any sample code snippet would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [XML Tag Library's Transformation Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakq.html#bnakv) to transform XML with XSLT in your JSP page without any additional Java code.

Comment: Is there any other alternative apart from transforming XML with XSLT in the JSP page?  Above mentioned transformation will help me to display HTML elements and their attributes but in addition to this I also want to perform other operations like load the data from table into these html components, perform add,delete and modify operation on the records displayed on the web page.